# Active Bootstrap Buttons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have just been playing around with Bootstraps Button Group to show and hide div's on my webpage. Perhaps I am being dumb, but could anyone point me in the right direction for making the selected button active when clicked?

HTML (Buttons):

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
     <button id="1" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
     <button id="2" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
     <button id="3" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
$("#1").click(function(){
    $("#first-section").show();
    $("#second-section").hide();
    $("#third-section").hide();
});

$("#2").click(function(){
    $("#first-section").hide();
    $("#second-section").show();
    $("#third-section").hide();
});

$("#3").click(function(){
    $("#first-section").hide();
    $("#second-section").hide();
    $("#third-section").show();
});
</script>
```

I assume I have to do something near the .show() on each function, so apply the active class on the button. Any pushes in the right direction would be  great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a class that activates the button on click: for example clicked maybe? Untested but it should work fine

[The ToggleClass method:](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp)

> This method checks each element for the specified class names. The
>   class names are added if missing, and removed if already set - This
>   creates a toggle effect.

```
(".btn").click(function() {
   // Instead of directly editing CSS, toggle a class
   $(".btn").removeClass("clicked");//removes classes everywhere
   $(this).toggleClass("clicked");//adds the class at the right button
});
.clicked {
   background-color: #differentcolorhere;
}
```

you can do it automatically for each button too

```
<script>
$("#1").click(function(){
    $("#first-section").show();
    $("#second-section").hide();
    $("#third-section").hide();

});

$("#2").click(function(){
    $("#first-section").hide();
    $("#second-section").show();
    $("#third-section").hide();

});

$("#3").click(function(){
    $("#first-section").hide();
    $("#second-section").hide();
    $("#third-section").show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant! That worked great. One last question, how would I make it so that when another button is pushed the previous one is no longer changed? At the moment I have to click the button again to remove the toggled class. Thank you!

Comment: see my edit @DylanBuckley the toggleClass is supposed to remove the other clicked button and put it in the other one

Comment: They are all remaining with the new class applied until I click them again, at which point they revert back. Have tried in a few browsers too @CodingEnthusiast

Comment: @DylanBuckley use the removeClass in Jquery to fix it. Check my new Edit

Comment: Thank you! FYI to others, you can use the bootstrap class "active" if you don't wish to use a custom class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside your click events:

```
$(this).addClass('Active');
```

and before setting the Active, you can remove that class from all the buttons like this:

```
$("button.btn").removeClass('Active');
```

Comment: This creates the same effect as the below answer, however doesn't remove the class when another button is pressed.